The scroll over ul element is not working properly
I have a problem with scrolling my ul element, when my mouse is over the ul the scroll doesn't start to work until I move the scroll button on the right. Also, when the the list goes to the top or end scroll is always swiched to the scroll of the whole page. (the component doesn't have any parent or child elements)
How could I fix it?
HTML:
<div class="city-options" *ngIf="isCityToggled">
                    <form>
                      <div class="city-field d-flex mb-3">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass mr-2"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="custom-input" placeholder="Введіть населений пункт" matInput [formControl]="cityControl">
                      </div>
                        <ul>
                          <li *ngFor="let city of (filteredCityNames | async)" (click)="selectCity(city)">{{city}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </form>
                  </div>

CSS:
.city-options ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 200px;  /* Set a fixed height */
  overflow-y: auto;  /* Add a scrollbar when the content overflows the height */
}


Can you create a running example in CodeSandbox that reproduces the problem?

@Nahom SO requires the code to be in the question.

I think it wouldn't hurt if you add a link to a running example. And I don't think it needs to use Angular since it's a CSS issue.  I tried to reproduce it and failed.

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you put enough code into your question so we can see the problem and so help you. @Nahom, SO requires the code (preferably as a runnable snippet) within the question as external links may rot (can disappear) thus rendering the question useless to future readers.

@AHaworth SO editor does not support angular development due to the number of dependencies, SO editor is good for only Javascript, external editors are the only option for reliably debugging angular code,

Try making a few adjustments to your CSS, try setting the horizontal scroll to hidden and remove any default margin.
 overflow-x: hidden; margin: 0; 

